# salesforce dx command line error while exporting data

Tags: salesforcedx

While going through the salesforce dx trailhead, I am not able to export data from my dev hub org.

The error message prints an incomplete path and says that it is not recognized as an internal or external command

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Could you change the output directory here and try ? Thanks

Comment: believe you have space in your directory name.. either use a folder with no spaces in name or wrap the full path in quotes and try..

Comment: @Vamsi - yes I beleive the space is causing the problem.@Mohit, I am not sure which path I should change here

Comment: @Mohit - as per my command the output directory is C:\sfdx:\geolocation\data

Comment: That sounds like it might be a bug. I'll ask.

Comment: @sfdcfox If you have an update on this, I'd love to hear!

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to find a solution for this, but as a workaround I tried creating another dummy user. The username for the new user should not have whitespace character.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that SFDX does not handle spaces in the `LOCALAPPDATA` environment variable (while still claiming to support Windows).

The workaround is to use short names. In a command line, execute:

```
FOR %d IN ("%LOCALAPPDATA%") DO SET LOCALAPPDATA=%~sd
```

This command line is then ready for SFDX use.

Note : in a batch file, do not forget to [double the `%` sign](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
As a workaround instead of putting the query on the console I put it on a file and referenced the file like this:

-q ./query.txt

Comment: Works on Windows and a convenient workaround for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when running Salesforce CLI commands in Windows. I believe it's because of the use of "" in the command arguments. You can use Windows Power Shell instead. Windows Power Shell worked well for me and didn't complain about "" in commands.