# Sfdx export error on Windows 10

Tags: salesforcedx, trailhead, bug

I was going through the [App Development with Salesforce DX](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/sfdx_app_dev/units/sfdx_app_dev_create_app) trailhead and everything was going smoothly until I tried to export the sample data with the following command:

```
sfdx force:data:tree:export -q "SELECT Name, Location__Latitude__s, Location__Longitude__s FROM Account WHERE Location__Latitude__s != NULL AND Location__Longitude__s != NULL" -d ./data
```

I get the error

> 'C:\Users\Kasper' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.

Since the error message breaks off my Windows 10 username at the first white space I am assuming that this is the cause. I came across this question where it is suggested that it could be a bug: 
[salesforce dx command line error while exporting data](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/202144/salesforce-dx-command-line-error-while-exporting-data)

However, it states no solution expect to create a new Windows user. I'd really love a better solution or work around? Also, if you happen to have a space in your Windows username and got it to work I'd love to know.

On a side note, does anyone have any experience with reporting bugs in SFDX? Is that better or worse than the normal process of reporting bugs?

Comment: As with the other question, looks like DX may be struggling with whitespace in the username - have you tried running it from a directory that doesn't have whitespace in it in case that's the issue?

Comment: @berry120 Thanks for the suggestion. That was what I thought too. I copied the directory to a different place but that didn't help. To be absolutely certain just I started the trailhead from the beginning in a new directory without any spaces, but it didn't solve the problem. If you have more suggestions I'd love to hear them!

Comment: Hmm, that is odd - what's the error you get when you run it from a directory without spaces?

Comment: Same error. I suspect that somewhere it is referencing my Windows user directory without escaping the white spaces. I find it hard to believe this is a bug since so many people have white spaces in their Windows user names.

Comment: Asking in the MVP channel. I'll see if I get anything this time.

Comment: @Kasper Putting a space in a user name in Windows is just asking for trouble. SFDX isn't the only software I've ever seen that has issues with it. Even some Microsoft tools have had issues with spaces in the past. In fact, the default user creation for Windows 10 Home is to use just the first name of the user.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you very much for checking! I have never even heard of this as an issue. But I'll take your word for it, and look into changing my Windows user name.

Comment: @sfdcfox I've never had a problem with spaces in directory names, except with tools ported from other platforms by developers who made too many assumptions about how Windows works (e.g. every Oracle tool I met, Ruby or Python). They're usually fooled by using short names during installation, though. But not in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [answered there](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/221850/53646): it would seem that SFDX does not handle spaces in the `LOCALAPPDATA` environment variable (while still claiming to support Windows).

The workaround is to use short names. In a command line, execute:

```
FOR %d IN ("%LOCALAPPDATA%") DO SET LOCALAPPDATA=%~sd
```

This command line is then ready for SFDX use.

Note : in a batch file, do not forget to [double the `%` sign](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for).

Comment: Hi Mac! Thank you for your answer. After I heard of @sfdxfox solution I changed my Windows username to one without spaces. However after that i got swamped with other projects so I haven't been able to test if that solves my problem. (I hope to do that soon.) I like your solution a lot though, because I now know that switching Windows user names is quite a bit of work and error prone too.

Comment: any downsides to this, is it going to change options that may break other apps in any way?